# Wireless does not work (ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

I'm new to linux and installed Ubuntu 13.04 32bit on an older Dell Inspiron E1705 laptop. Both the wireless and wired ethernet connections are not recognized. I would appreciate any help getting either working but wireless would be the most useful. The WLAN card is a Broadcom BCM4311 b/g internal card. Please help Ubuntu power users, you are my only hope!

Comment: New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the [help/on-topic]. These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: @EricCarvalho The duplicate you quoted is misleading and, in several places, absolutely incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will follow the linked troubleshooting or switch to a current release and resubmit my question.

Comment: @chili555 The second answer (by Luis Alvarado) explains in details how to install the driver for OP's card. How can this be misleading? I have installed the driver for BCM4311 several times by following that exact instructions. I'm sure it is not incorrect.

Comment: @EricCarvalho I'm sorry, Additional Drivers, aka bcmwl-kernel-source is incorrect for Broadcom 4311. I will be happy to provide the same documentation I supplied to Luis.

Comment: @chili555 Two years ago I had to install Ubuntu 12.04 on many Dell Inspiron laptops at my work place. BCM4311 was one of the WLAN chips. I installed STA driver (bcmwl-kernel-source) because it only downloads deb packages (from a apt cache in my case) while firmware-b43-installer downloads a firmware from Internet and I didn't want to deal with proxy/firewall settings. STA driver always worked for me.

Comment: @EricCarvalho In what manner may I provide my documentation? Luis and I are working on a massive edit of his answer.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and will absolutely try to remove install the firmware-b43-installer and uninstall the proprietary driver in 12.04 if troubleshooting does not solve the issue.

Comment: @chili555 Could you post a link in a chat room? Please note that I'm not, in any way, saying you're wrong. Sorry if that was the impression you got. I was only reporting my experiences, only empirical knowledge. As I'm very interested in how things work I will surely read the docs (and maybe even replace my drivers).

Comment: @EricCarvalho I wrote a 5-6 paragraph email to Luis. I'll be glad to get your email address in chat or give mine. How do I get to the chat? I was in no way offended. My only agenda is for the users to get the right info.

Comment: @EricCarvalho LOL! This case is just one more example!

Comment: @EricCarvalho email sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please hook up the ethernet and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe b44
```

Your ethernet should now be working. Now do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and both should now be working. If it is not yet working, please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot. If it is still not working, look for clues here:

```
rfkill list all
dmesg | grep -e b44 -e eth0
```

The driver b44 is correct for your ethernet device. Your system shouldn't hang loading the correct driver. Please run:

```
dmesg > wifi.txt
lsmod >> wifi.txt
```

Find the file wifi.txt in your user directory and transfer it on a USB drive or similar and paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your reply.

Comment: after sudo modprobe b44 and entering my su password and enter, a white blinking cursor appears on a blank line. I have waited and nothing has happened.

Comment: Get back the command prompt with Ctrl+c. When you click the Network Manager icon, does it show an ethernet connection? Please confirm your ethernet device: lspci -nn | greo 0200 Thanks.

Comment: `lspci -nn | grep 0200` returns `03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)` Nothing except Network Proxy is shown. There are no network connections. I appreciate the quick responses. I should add that there is a blue wifi button (Fn + F2) but pressing it does nothing.

Comment: B44 is correct for your ethernet. Is it still hung? Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes. I created an ethernet connection to test and it still hangs after `sudo modprobe b44`

Comment: `rfkill list all
dmesg | grep -e b44 -e eth0`

Tried these and did not return any results.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7105559/

Comment: bcmwl-kernel-source is still installed. Please retrace your steps, purge it and reboot.

Comment: I purged bcmwl-kernal-source and rebooted and have a wired connection now! :)

Comment: Awesome! Now install the b43 firmware.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` returned:
E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer

Comment: Please try: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer  Pardon my oops.

Comment: everything else updated except:
E: Invalid operation linux-firmware-nonfree

Comment: Problem solved (I have both wired and wireless connectivity):
`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
restart
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
restart one more time
and PROBLEM SOLVED. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Other useful steps for the accepted answer.

Links to .deb packages for Ubuntu 13.04 / Raring:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/i386/linux-firmware-nonfree/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/i386/b43-fwcutter/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/kernel/firmware-b43-installer

Then:
sudo dpkg -i each_downloaded_package